# Good schema for neo4j DB

Tags: graph, neo4j

What is the best design for social sharing network based on phonebook?

Background:
App sync the phonebook of a contact and social network of a user and build a graph and give recommendations.

Use case:
1. Recommendation of friends, mutual friends to people in your phonebook.
2. Initially not many nodes user connects to has social linkage therefore it may be the
   case you have lot of friends but very few of them are social friends. Does it make sense
   to have new relationship for every social ID (be bbm, FB, linkedin)
3. We will build the network through which old user gets notification when new user joins 
   any of social network and register to our app.
4. Pick of the day - based on mutual friends (degree and social interest and country), user
   can search country wise social IDs.
5. User always search people from 1 country or its connected node (upto 4 degree) based on 
   male/female and age filter.
6. Status update would be notified to other connected nodes with social IDs.

Schema:
Country (1 relation or bucket per country).
Friend (all people who are in phonebook) - phonenumber as a key.
Social friend (1 relation or bucket per social networking company - will update the relation as soon as someone from your phonebook updates the social linkage on our site).
1 relation for male - help for filtering and pick suggestions.
1 relation for female  help for filtering and pick suggestions.

Does it make sense to also add friends and social friends as a relation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do something like this:

```
(u:User { phone : "phone#" })-[:ON_PHONE]->(u2:User { phone : "phone#" })

(u:User { phone : "phone#" })-[:KNOWS]->(u2:User:Facebook { phone : "phone#", fbid: "fbid" })
```

If you want to keep the record information where the social network connections came from you can add the additional links to your graph like this:

```
(u:User { phone : "phone#" })-[:KNOWS_ON_FB]->(:FacebookUser {fbid:"fbid"})<-[:ON_FB]-(u2:User { phone : "phone#", fbid: "fbid" })
```

I think in most cases you don't need keep the records and should just focus on the "realtime/current" structure of your graph that you can update.

You can add additional labels to your users if you have facebook, linkedin etc. information for them and then add additional indexes:

```
create index on :User(phone)
create index on :Facebook(fbid)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for the suggested schema.I am thinking to opt for knows_on<social network> considering there may be in future SAAS model based on our initial work.I believe businesses would like the fact if relations are maintained separately & we can also record information where the social network connections came from.With that being said,do you think we would need country as a separate relation for scalability as we have users that search for users(on the social network) in a specific country.We are using filter of country and male/female as another relation.is this correct?